# Java. Trying to adjust the attempts a user has to unlock a lock in a program and finalizing program

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
public class GentCPT3
{
  public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    BufferedReader objReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (System.in)); 

      System.out.println("Enter key");
      int key1 = Integer.parseInt(objReader.readLine()); // set to 111  

      System.out.println("Enter key2");
      int key2 = Integer.parseInt(objReader.readLine()); // set to 222

      Lock lock1 = new Lock (key1);

      Lock lock2 = new Lock (key2);

      System.out.println(lock1.isOpen); // prints false

      lock1.close();
      lock2.close();
      lock1.open(111); // opens lock1
      lock2.open(222); // opens lock2111
      lock1.close();
      lock1.close();

    }
  }
class Lock //Initializing class
{
  //Initializing variables
  boolean isOpen;
  int key; 
  int numAttempts = 0;

  Lock(int key) 
  {
    isOpen = false; 
    this.key = key;
  } 

  public void close()//for incorrect combo 
  {
    isOpen = false;
  } 
  public void open(int key)//for correct combo
  { 
    if(this.key == key) 
    {
      System.out.println("Opened");
      isOpen = true;
    } 
    else if(!isOpen) 
    {
      numAttempts++;
    } 
    if(numAttempts == 3) 
    {
      System.out.println("ALARM");//prints alarm when the combo is incorrect 3 times
    } 
  } 
}
```

as of right now, my program only gives me two attempts and then is gives me an output of false when I want it to say ALARM. Edit the code if you like and comment exactly what I should do. I also have some more debugging that would be nice if I got some help with so that I can have a fully functional program

Comment: You need to learn how to use a debugger and step through your code one line at a time to see whats actually happening. You can find guides on google or youtube for doing this with Eclipse or Intellij or whatever IDE you're using.

Comment: Why are you expecting it to print "ALARM" if you've only made 2 attempts?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't getting two attempts right now. What you are seeing currently is the output from this set of code:

```
System.out.println("Enter key");
int key1 = Integer.parseInt(objReader.readLine()); // set to 111  

System.out.println("Enter key2");
int key2 = Integer.parseInt(objReader.readLine()); // set to 222

Lock lock1 = new Lock (key1);
Lock lock2 = new Lock (key2);

System.out.println(lock1.isOpen); // prints false
```

You currently only have one open attempt for each lock. If you add more open attempts like:

```
lock1.open(111); // opens lock1
lock2.open(222); // opens lock2
lock1.open(111); // opens lock1
lock2.open(222); // opens lock2
lock1.open(111); // opens lock1
lock2.open(222); // opens lock2
```

It will print out your expected behaviour

Comment: Pretty much what I need is that for each individual lock is that if the same lock receives 3 failed attempts on a row. It prints the message ALARM.

Comment: My answer addresses your problem. As I said you aren't attempting to open the locks three times in your code right now.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right, you want to the Locks to be OPEN by default? If so, just change to this:

```
Lock(int key) 
{
    isOpen = true; // < true as default (instead of false)
    this.key = key;
}
```

This leads to the following output:

- true
- Opened
- Opened

Comment: Pretty much what I need is that for each individual lock is that if the same lock receives 3 failed attempts on a row. It prints the message ALARM.